# Angular Universal : SSR, Error "no such file or directory, open 'dist\browser\index.html'"

Tags: angular

After fixing the document is not defined Error by following solution in server.ts:

```
const domino = require("domino");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const templateA = fs
  .readFileSync(path.join("dist/browser", "index.html"))
  .toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(templateA);
win.Object = Object;
win.Math = Math;

global["window"] = win;
global["document"] = win.document;
global["branch"] = null;
global["object"] = win.object;
```

I am getting a new Error after starting the server (npm run serve:ssr)

```
internal/fs/utils.js:269
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'dist\browser\index.html'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)
    at Module.uj+Y (C:\Projects\general-ledger-office-v1.0\dist\general-ledger-office\server\main.js:1:4191488)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Projects\general-ledger-office-v1.0\dist\general-ledger-office\server\main.js:1:317)
    at Object.0 (C:\Projects\general-ledger-office-v1.0\dist\general-ledger-office\server\main.js:1:16528)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Projects\general-ledger-office-v1.0\dist\general-ledger-office\server\main.js:1:317)
    at +rOU (C:\Projects\general-ledger-office-v1.0\dist\general-ledger-office\server\main.js:1:2251)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\general-ledger-office-v1.0\dist\general-ledger-office\server\main.js:1:2296)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'dist\\browser\\index.html'
}
```

Comment: What is your folder structure. a

Comment: you can try using __dirname to make absolute path.